# TypeScript and iCalendar Generator (ics) - Difficulties to define the "start" attribute when defining the DateArray object

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, icalendar

I'm creating an Express/TypeScript app that needs to generate an iCalendar object by receiving some of the parameters in a JSON in a request but i am getting the error message "Types of property 'start' are incompatible; Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'DateArray'; Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number, number]'; Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.". My "event" variable is defined as it follows:

`const event = start: [parseInt(year), month, day, hour, minute]`;

My code is:

`import * as ics from "ics";`

`interface IcsCreatorTextRequest { year: string; month: number; day: number; hour: number; minute: number; duration: number; title: string; description: string; url: string; invited: string[]; }`

`const event = {start: [parseInt(year), month, day, hour, minute], duration: { hours: duration },[...]`

[...]

`ics.createEvent(event);`

Comment: Format should be as follow: 
[2018, 5, 30, 6, 30]
example https://www.npmjs.com/package/ics